# creating a new layer/selection based on the conditions in Python script?

Tags: arcpy, layers

Is there any easy way how to write a python script, which would create a new layer based on location from a border line and "if" condition?

I have two layers A and B, both are made of several polygons. I need to select those polygons from both layers based on location, e.g. 1000 meters, they must touch each other or the border line, and based on comparing their attribute values of one selected column. Then i need to create a new selection or layer, if the difference between the values is big enough.

I mean something like "if column.A - column.B > x ^ polygon.A and polygon.B touch each other or the line/or the distance is 1000meters from the line, then create a new layer of those two polygons"

Comment: Welcome. Please edit your question to include some code snippets of what you have already tried or what specifically you are having trouble with.